# How to add a directory to a path?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, pip, jupyter-lab

I am trying to install jupyterlab via the command terminal and it gave me the following warning:

WARNING: The script jupyter-server.exe is installed in 'C:\Users\Benedict\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress thus warning, use  --no-warn-script-location.

Please how do I add the directory to PATH? Someone help me please. Thank you

Comment: see this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IolxqkL7cD8) by Corey Schafer on setting enviromental variables.

Answer (score 0):

**As i can see, you haven't put that in path, for doing that follow the following step:-**

1. Open the advance system settings
2. select environment variable
3. Then click on path and press edit.
4. Click on new and enter the you path and then your path to python script directory.
5. Press okay and reopen the jupyter.
6. That's it